# Call 'new' constructor Function from java

Tags: jxbrowser

Is it possible to call the new operator to create a new javascript object directly from java obtaining a JSObject?

for example, I know I can do:

browser.executeJavaScript("var myString = new String('Hello World');"); and then I could do: JSObject hello = browser.executeJavaScript("myString"), to get the myString object into java.  Is it possible to to this in one call?  Something like

JSObject hello = new JSString("Hello World")?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to instantiate JavaScript object on Java side:

```
JSObject object = browser.getJSContext().createObject();
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir...

However, if I understand correctly there is little difference between calling 'new' on a method and actually calling the method with 'f(arg1, arg2....)'.  jxBrowser provides 'invoke' to call a javascript method (that can create and return JSObjects), shouldn´t this be the same with 'new'?  And probably calling 'new' on a script will be converted to calling some method in Java to interface with Chromium.  Couldn´t you make this method public?

Anyhow, I will use a script with 'new'... 

Thanx!

Comment: I think it's possible, but we need to take a look deeply to find out how it can be implemented. Anyway, I created appropriate feature request in our issue tracking system and linked it with this topic. When new functionality will be available for download, I will let you know.

Comment: I have updated the answer where I show how to do this.